# json array parsing issue with logstash

Tags: json, logstash, graylog

We want to implement service request trace using http plugin of logstash in JSON Array format.

We are getting the following error when trying to parse the JSON array:

error:

```
:message=>"gsub mutation is only applicable for Strings, skipping", :field=>"message", :value=>nil, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/filters/mutate.rb", :line=>"322", :method=>"gsub"}
:message=>"Exception in filterworker", "exception"=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Only String and Array types are splittable. field:message is of type = NilClass>
```

My json array is :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "appName": "DemoApp",
            "appVersion": "1.1",
            "deviceId": "1234567",
            "deviceName": "moto e",
            "deviceOSVersion": "5.1",
            "packageName": "com.DemoApp",
            "message": "testing null pointer exception",
            "errorLog": "null pointer exception"
        },
        {
            "appName": "DemoApp",
            "appVersion": "1.1",
            "deviceId": "1234567",
            "deviceName": "moto e",
            "deviceOSVersion": "5.1",
            "packageName": "com.DemoApp",
            "message": "testing illegal state exception",
            "errorLog": "illegal state exception"
        }
    ]
}
```

my logstash config is :

```
    input {
            http {
            codec => "plain"
            }
    }
    filter{
            json {
                  source => "message"
                 }
            mutate { gsub => [ "message", "},", "shr" ] }
            split {
                  terminator => "shr"
                  field => "data"
           }
    }
    }


output {
 stdout { codec => "json" }
    gelf{
        host => localhost
        facility => "%{type}"
        level =>["%{SeverityLevel}", "INFO"]
        codec => "json"
    }
       file{
        path => "/chroot/result.log"
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you would escape special chars in the regex: `mutate { gsub => [ "message", "\}\,\r\n\r\n\{", "\}shr\{" ] }`

Comment: @Kadir I tried your above suggestion as well.. But I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash has a default metadata field named **message**. So your json `message` field is overlapping that. Consider changing **json** field name `message` to another.

The other option maybe using `target` setting and referencing the target field like:

```
json { source => "message" target => "data"}
mutate { gsub => [ "[data][message]", "\}\,\r\n\r\n\{", "\}shr\{" ] }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @kair tried the above config as well... still getting the same error.


`{:timestamp=>"2017-02-07T11:02:00.192000+0530", :message=>"gsub mutation is only applicable for Strings, skipping", :field=>"[data][message]", :value=>nil, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/filters/mutate.rb", :line=>"322", :method=>"gsub"}`

Comment: ok I am now able to split my data.... have edited my config accordingly. I am now facing a new issue. My fields are being renamed as : **data_appName** instead of just being **appName**.  Any suggestion as to how to avoid this and get the field name that is needed.    I have tried out the following to achieve it as well :     
` mutate
        {
              rename => {"data_appName" => "appName"}
        }`

But still got no positive output.

Comment: As far as i know `mutate { rename => {"[data][appName]" => "appName"} }` should work. A better way is to rename all fields like above then remove the **data** field.
`mutate {
            rename => [
                    "[data][appName]", "appName",
                    "[data][appVersion]", "appVersion",
     ..
     ..
            ]
            remove_field => "data"
    }`